# Authorization completed with an error com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed

Tags: android, firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth

i am integrating Google sign in and Twitter login in My App under single Activity but when i click on twitter login button it authorizes account but then pushes back to mainActivity with the error below mentioned.Google Signin works Normally but clciking on twitter login button after authorizes sends back to mainactivity.

```
Authorization completed with an error
   com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed.
      at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.handleAuthorize(TwitterAuthClient.java:112)
      at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.authorize(TwitterAuthClient.java:103)
      at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton$LoginClickListener.onClick(TwitterLoginButton.java:160)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5106)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20329)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zyg
```

**MY MAINACTIVITY CODE IS**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


     SignInButton signInButton;
     TwitterLoginButton mLoginButton;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
     GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
     FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private static final String TAG = "GoogleActivity";
    private static final String TAGS = "TwitterLogin";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private static final int RC_TWITTER= 9002;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //COnfigure twitter sdk
        TwitterAuthConfig authConfig=new TwitterAuthConfig(
                getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_key),
                getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret)
        );


        TwitterConfig twitterConfig=new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .twitterAuthConfig(authConfig)
                .build();
        Twitter.initialize(twitterConfig);

        //config twitter
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        signInButton=findViewById(R.id.sign_in_btn);
        //Twitter //
        mLoginButton=findViewById(R.id.twitter_login);
        mLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                Log.d(TAG, "twitterLogin:success" + result);
                handleTwitterSession(result.data);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Log.w(TAG, "twitterLogin:failure", exception);
                //updateUI(null);
            }
        });
        //Twitter//
        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
// profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        //If you are trying to implement Sign In, i.e. you want to get back user identity,
        // you can start with new GoogleSignInOptions(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN),
        //GoogleSignInOptions is options used to configure the GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API.
        //Api entry point for Google Sign In.
        //You must pass your server's client ID to the requestIdToken method. To find the OAuth 2.0 client ID:
        //Open the Credentials page in the API Console.
       // The Web application type client ID is your backend server's OAuth 2.0 client ID.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso=new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail().build();

        mGoogleSignInClient= GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso);

        // [START initialize_auth]
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // [END initialize_auth]
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signIn();
            }
        });

    }
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                // ...
            }
        }
        if (requestCode==RC_TWITTER){
            // Pass the activity result to the Twitter login button.
            mLoginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }


    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(),null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Welcome.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Signed In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        //    updateUI(user);
                        }
                        else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_layout), "Authentication Failed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //updateUI(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }



    // [START on_start_check_user]
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    }
    // [END on_start_check_user]
   //twitter
    private void handleTwitterSession(TwitterSession session) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleTwitterSession:" + session);

        AuthCredential credential = TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
                session.getAuthToken().token,
                session.getAuthToken().secret);

        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");

                            Intent twitterIntent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,Welcome.class);
                            startActivity(twitterIntent);
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                           // updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
    //twitter

}
```

Comment: make sure you added TwitterKit for Android in your app console at https://apps.twitter.com

Answer (score 1):

add following callback scheme in your app console at https://apps.twitter.com

```
twittersdk://
```

for more information: 
https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/issues/134

Answer (score 0):

`if(requestCode==RC_TWITTER){

```
        // Pass the activity result to the Twitter login button.

        mLoginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }`
```

RC_TWITTER didn't use

please use in Intent that's why you getting this

Comment: From Review:  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks